# Django form fields not rendering in template

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to render a simple Django Form on my index page. I have stripped it way back in an attempt to get it to work.

I can display other context elements when passing them in, and I know an instance of the Form is being created (by printing `type(form)`), it is just empty and I cannot figure out why. I have made similar forms multiple times before without running into this issue.

I have tried rendering as `{{ form.as_p }}` as well as `{{ form }}`.

All that renders is the heading, the hidden csrf_token, and the submit button.

Thanks in advance...

```js
from django import forms

class NewPostForm(forms.Form):
    title: forms.CharField(label='Title', max_length=100)
    content: forms.CharField(label='Content', max_length=100)

def index(request):
    form = NewPostForm()
    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "form": form
    })
```

```html
{% block body %}
<div class="new-post">
    <h5>New Post</h5>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Add Post">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you have typo in your code, `title:` should be `title = `, same for `contect`

Comment: OMG! Thank you @ahmed. My brain is fried going back and forth between JS and Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo in the declaration of the form fields. I used colon instead of equals.